# How to omit the AreaPath folders from MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing an MVC4 app and want to omit the AreaPath FolderNames from the URL displayed to the end user.

**Actual Path**
/Areapath/FolderName/ControllerName/Action/Index

Currently the End user see it as
http://**sitenames/FolderName**/ControllerName/Action/Index

I wanted it be displayed as

http://**sitenames**/ControllerName/Action/Index

Comment: You mean you want that routing but still using areas?

Comment: Yes Biplov. I want the routing using areas

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to not have areapath in your routing while using areas. What you could do is create different project instead of areas and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted it be displayed as
>
> `http://sitenames/ControllerName/Action/Index`

No need to use an area to achieve this. You could directly put your controllers in the main part and rely on the default routing.

Comment: Size of application is big and for modularity and maintenance  purpose i would like to segregate the application into different modules like Admin, Security, Customers etc. The way suggested by Darin is not feasible as the number of controllers in current applications is more than 50 and increasing.

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to reconsider your routes then. With areas you need to specify the area name, otherwise I don't know how you expect ASP.NET MVC to know where to dispatch the request.

Comment: agreed. That's the reason am reaching out to other guys if anybody has done any tweaking wrt to routing and areas